# C# How to make a bounds fit to a Camera that is rotated

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity I have a class that is creating a new bounds, for those of you who may not know unity bounds is just really a cube. I then have a object like a Camera, I want to add this bounds to the camera and scale it to fit around the view frustum.  That would be easy if it never rotated but the camera does rotate and at the moment I am drawling a blank.

this is what I have right now witch works when the Camera does not rotate

```
    float h = Mathf.Tan(cam.fov * Mathf.Deg2Rad * .5f) * cam.farClipPlane * 2;
    Vector3 scale = new Vector3(h * cam.aspect, h, cam.farClipPlane);

    newBounds.center = cam.transform.position + cam.transform.forward * (cam.farClipPlane/2);
    newBounds.size = scale;
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we set bounds on a BoxCollider we only set the Size and Center of the bounds only and these bounds contain the size and center with respect to the local position and rotation
 so, you don't need to write the code for rotation just set the

`transform.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().center` and 
`transform.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().size`

and the bounds will automatically rotate according to the Transform of the GameObject

Comment: Im not using a box collider, im not use any type of collider.  This is not for a collision.  I just need to know the area that contains a camera and its view frust but not the view frust itself.  In script I am creating a bounds by doing 

Bounds newBounds = new bounds()

Comment: the also store the parents rotation and write your methods accordingly.
this is also how unity does things parent Transformations are applied to bounds before collision checking
   To know more you need to explain what you need to do with these bounds????

Comment: What I am doing with the bounds is I have a dynamic Occlusion culling system I wrote for a streaming world.  I have all that working and it only checks the objects in the view frust.  The problem is that the closer to the far plane the objects are the more poping that happens.  so my solution to this is create a bounds that contains the camera but is going to be bigger than the frust(right now till I get rotation working just the same size + the extra stuff since its not a frustum).  but for this to work I need it to resize based off the rotation